# How to use @Query annotation for mongodb queries along with the derived query methods that has a limit

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I have an existing mongo repo, that does not use `@Query` annotations like,

```java
// model
@Document(collection="foo")
public class Foo {
  private String id;
  private String businessKey;
  private Date createdDate;

}

// repository
public interface FooRepo extends MongoRepository<Foo, String> {
  Foo findTopByBusinessKeyOrderByCreatedDateAsc(String businessKey);
}
```

How can I change derived query method to use `@Query` but still somehow `findTop..` ? I don't want the call site passing in `Pageable`

```java
// repository
public interface FooRepo extends MongoRepository<Foo, String> {

  // how can I use limit/top now? 
  @Query(value="{ businessKey: ?0, someFilter: { $exists: false } }", sort="{ createdDate: 1 }")
  Foo renamedMethod(String businessKey);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've found one approach to work around the problem,

```
public interface FooRepo extends MongoRepository<Foo, String> {

  default Foo findTopByBusinessKeyOrderByCreatedDateAsc(String businessKey){
    List<Foo> shouldBeOnlyOneFoo = findOneFoo(businessKey, Pageable.ofSize(1));
    if (shouldBeOnlyOneFoo.isEmpty()) {
      return null;
    }
    return shouldBeOnlyOneFoo.get(0);
  }

  @Query(value="{ businessKey: ?0, newField: { $exists: false } }", sort="{ createdDate: 1 }")
  List<Foo> findOneFoo(String businessKey, Pageable pageLimit);
}
```

I've to write 20 default impls like the above, but atleast it works. Still curious to know if there's any other ways to do it. It seems a overkill when all I need to do is add another filter to existing repository methods.